Vauxhall/Opel Corsa D/E Gearbox clicking while turning spline manually by hand. Is it normal?
I removed the manual transmission gearbox to install new clutch and I noticed that when I turned the gearbox spline by hand it was making this funny clicking noise. Before the removal it drove fine. Shifts into gear properly and plenty of biting point. So I was just wondering whether this clicking noise is normal or not on this type of gearbox.
Engine is A14XER/B14XER
Below is the link to the video of the clicking noise I recorded with my phone.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPZTsEON8Y1uSsNubuu6_r9tBV3bYsuy/view
